# code not working after upgrading to jdeveloper 11g

Tags: java, jdeveloper

i migrated my struts project from jdeveloper 10.3.4 to 11g.
A simple java code that was working fine has stopped working.

```
return (List<HardwareType>)dao.selectAll();
```

the `selectAll()` method `returns List<CommonDomain>` which I am typecasting as above.
And-- `public class HardwareType extends CommonDomain{`

all this was working fine in jDeveloper 10g.
Even if jdeveloper 11g uses java 7 , i don't think java 7 can break this code.

Comment: The syntax might not be supported in Java7. Post more code.

Answer (score 0):

When you say it is not working, do you mean that it is not compiling or that it is not running properly? What is the error that you are getting?
If it is a compile error - check which libraries are associated with your project under project properties.